# How to ensure an accordion closes when you select another one to open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stumped at trying to work out how to input the required code to ensure an active accordion will close when clicking on another one.

I've seen other fiddle's that show working solutions but have no idea how to fit it into my current code despite trying (am a newbie to Javascript).

The HTML:

```
<button class="syo-accordion"><h3>Sample Heading</h3></button>
     <div class="syo-panel"> <p>Some text example</p></div>
```

The Javascript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("syo-accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When click to the accordion and adding `.active` class to it, Right before this step you should check if other accordion has the `.active` class already added to it and remove it.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("syo-accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {

    for (const accordion of acc) { // looping through all of the accorion
        if (accordion.classList.contains("active")) {
            accordion.classList.remove("active"); // removing class if it contains the active class
        }
    }

    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this still doesn't seem to be working. When I click on an accordion it opens, but any others open don't seem to shut still.